# How can I download a kaggle dataset on my Colab notebook?

Tags: dataset, data-science

Can someone help me with downloading Kaggle dataset on my Colab Notebook? I am new to Colab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following method to download any kaggle dataset to your Colab notebook.

1. First, you have to create an API key in [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com).
2. Go to kaggle.com and open your user settings page.
3. From the API access section download an API key.
4. A file called `kaggle.json` will be downloaded to your computer.
5. Now open your Colab notebook and copy the following snippet to a cell.

   `from google.colab import files`

   `files.upload()`

   After executing this upload the `kaggle.json` file.
6. Install the kaggle API using `!pip install -q kaggle` and move `kaggle.json` file to `~/.kaggle`

   `!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle`

   `!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/`
7. Now you can download the dataset to your Colab notebook by copying the API command of the dataset that you want to download.
   For example:

   `!kaggle competitions download -c titanic`

The dataset should get downloaded to your notebook after this. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

its neccessary to set up kaggle
for example

import json
import os
import shutil
import random
import cv2
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

```
KAGGLE_PATH = "/root/.kaggle"
if os.path.exists(KAGGLE_PATH):
  !rm -r "$KAGGLE_PATH"

!mkdir "$KAGGLE_PATH"
!touch "$KAGGLE_PATH/kaggle.json"

# https://www.kaggle.com/
api_token = {"username":"your username","key":"your api key"}

with open(KAGGLE_PATH+'/kaggle.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(api_token, file)

!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json
```

now you can download the dataset:

```
if not os.path.exists('./task'):

  os.makedirs('task')
else:
  !rm -rf task
  os.makedirs('task')

!kaggle datasets download -d user/explorer -p task
%pwd

!unzip -qn '/content/task/explorer.zip' -d /content/task > /dev/null
!rm /content/task/explorer.zip
```

this command
!kaggle datasets download -d user/explorer

you can get from 3dots right side, more info: [kaggle dataset download 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75569191/kaggle-dataset-download-403-forbidden)