# kaggle dataset download 403 Forbidden

Tags: download, dataset, kaggle

Tried to download a kaggle dataset and got 403 Forbidden.

```
$ kaggle datasets download -d abdz82/yolov1
403 - Forbidden
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a novice mistake but others may have the same issue as it is a bit confusing.

I thought the page that have **Data** tab is the page where I could download the dataset and get API command.

[image]

Copied the `<owner>/<dataset>` which is `abdz82/yolov1` and run download command.

```
$ kaggle datasets download -d abdz82/yolov1
403 - Forbidden
```

---

Actually I needed to click the dataset name PascalVOC_YOLO which took me to the actual page to download.

[image]

```
kaggle datasets download -d aladdinpersson/pascalvoc-yolo
```